# Domain/Definition of the Zeta Function

Tags: riemann-zeta, analytic-functions

I am curious about the definition of the $\zeta(s)$. Of course the $p$-series definition does not converge for $Re(s)<1$, so analytic continuation is required. Previously I have read that the functional equation is applicable to the whole complex plane except $s \neq 1$. Naively however, it does not seem to work on the critical strip. E.g., $\zeta(1/3) = ... \times \zeta(2/3)$, but $\zeta(2/3)$ would invoke $\zeta(1/3)$ and we have an issue. Similarly, $\zeta(3) = ... \times \zeta(-2)$, which would mean that $\zeta(2n+1) = 0, n \in \mathbb{N}$, but that is certainly not true.

Hence, I wanted to know whether it was appropriate to define it as,

$ \zeta(s) = \begin{cases} 
      \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s} & Re(s) > 1 \\
      \frac{1}{1-2^{1-s}} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^s} & 0 < Re(s) < 1 \\
      2^s \pi^{s-1} \sin(\frac{\pi s}{2}) \Gamma(1-s) \zeta(1-s) & Re(s)<0 
   \end{cases}
$

Comment: For the case $\Re(s)<0$ you need to prove the functional equation. You can show a meromorphic continuation to $\Bbb C\setminus 1$ without it, though - see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2768931/extending-zeta-to-a-meromorphic-function-on-mathbbc-1), and other ones.

Comment: Thank you! I will look at those posts.

Comment: You definition does not include $\Re(s)\in\{0,1\}$, and it's really not so much a definition as a way to evaluate $\zeta(s)$. The functional equation $\zeta(s)=2^s\ \pi^{s-1} \sin\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)\ \Gamma(1-s)\ \zeta (1-s)$ is valid at positive integers in a limit sense: $\underset{s\to 3}{\text{lim}}\left(2^s\ \pi^{s-1} \sin\left(\frac{\pi  s}{2}\right) \Gamma (1-s) \zeta(1-s)\right)=-4 \pi^2\ \zeta'(-2)=\zeta(3)$. It's also valid in the critical strip, but requires a representation that converges in the critical strip to be useful in the critical strip.

Comment: Got it! Oh alright, I thought the $\frac{1}{1-2^{1-s}} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^s}$ accounted for $\mathfrak{R}(s) \in {0,1}$. Thank you for your response!